# Excel (2010) Convert Formatted Value to its Text Equivalent

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-2010, plaintext

I have a spreadsheet containing thousands of quiz questions and answers for an online course that I am building.

**The spreadsheet is setup like this:**

- Question 1, Answer A, *Answer B, Answer C, Answer D
- Question 2, Answer A, Answer B, Answer C, *Answer D
- Question 3, *Answer A, Answer B, Answer C, Answer D

The correct answer for each question has an asterisk in front of it.

There are a wide variety of questions so many of the answers are of different formats.   Some are currency i.e. "$1.45" and others are formatted as dates like "January 23, 1987" and other answers are percentages like "47%".

I am using a Quiz building application which takes the excel spreadsheet and builds the quiz automatically from the spreadsheet; however, the issue is that it converts the excel data to plaintext.

Since some cells in the Excel spreadsheet are formatted as other types, such as Currency, Date and Percentage; they are changed when converted to plaintext - for example:

- "$1.45" is converted to "1.45"
- "January 23, 1987" is converted to "01/23/1987"
- "47%" is converted to "0.47"

This is an issue because I want the quiz to display the text equivalent to the formatted values; in other words I want them to be converted to text without changing from the way they look when they are in other formats; otherwise I will have to spend several months correcting the text by hand.

Does anyone know of a way to convert all formatted values in my spreadsheet to plaintext format **without making any changes** to the value that is displayed in the cell?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using VBA, you can change the values stored in the cells to their text equivalent (see the `.Text` property of the `Range` object.  I suppose if you then right-justified those cells, the value **displayed** would be the same.  But the actual value would be text and not numeric, so it would appear different in the formula bar.

Comment: Could you elaborate?   I am not familiar with VBA.

Comment: There are plenty of references to VBA on the internet. It is a programming language integrated with MS Excel that can be used to automate many functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that might work for you, but you can only process one worksheet at a time.

- Save the file as a `CSV` file
- Rename the file to a `*.txt` file
- **IMPORT** the file, and specify each column as being of type `Text`